# daemon function isn't working in CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos, centos6, daemon

I'm trying to daemonize a process under a different user.

In my init.d, I have a service which looks a little bit like this:

```
...
start() {
    echo "Starting mydaemon..."
    daemon --user someuser --name mydaemon mycommand
}
...
```

(entire script here: http://pastebin.com/bvpnsHgn)

However, all I get is `daemon: command not found`.

I checked that `daemon()` is declared in `/etc/init.d/functions`, but still, I cannot seem to use it.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you make sure to *source* the `/etc/init.d/functions` library in your service's init.d script?

You'd need this in your init.d script:

```
# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions
```

If this is already there, can you please post your daemon's start script?

Comment: I added that line, and it still does the same. I don't follow what you want me to paste? The entire file I gave the snippet from?

Comment: @CJxD Yep. Please do so.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bvpnsHgn

Comment: @CJxD I'm sorry. Can you try this with `. /etc/init.d/functions`, as I wrote in my answer?

Comment: Still have the same issue with either syntax.

Comment: Nevermind! It did work, the file just wasn't uploading to the server when I saved it. D'oh!

Comment: @CJxD What exactly worked?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11763/discussion-between-cjxd-and-ewwhite)

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing the scripts, you can simply (re)install them
this should get 
`daemon: command not found` issue resolved

```
yum install -y initscripts
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It is conceivable that a system could be messed up in a way where that command would help. It is however not a very likely explanation. The older answer provides a much more likely explanation of the symptoms (and it turned out to be the correct one).